# Compile C++ functions to Wasm

Tags: emscripten, webassembly

I read this [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/C_to_wasm) about wasm and after point 3. "Calling a custom function defined in C" I tried to figure out how to bind C++ functions and classes to JavaScript in that manner? Do I have to use [Embind](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.html#embind) there for, but how?

I also found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15865923/interaction-with-c-classes-in-emscripten) and the second answer from @lacenen could be a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time you just need to call a function in WASM.
So the simple way:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE MyFunc()
{
    printf("MyFunc()\n");
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Compiling with EmScripten you'll have a .js file with Module defined.
So on the JavaScript side you can use ccall -- here's the call without params or return value:

```
Module.ccall('MyFunc', null, null, null);
```

See: https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#interacting-with-code-ccall-cwrap